# How can we access windows service in webapplication using dot net

Tags: asp.net

I need to read the data from the COM port in a web application, so I have written a Windows Service for reading data from serial ports. Now I need to access that data in a web application. Can anyone tell me how to access it? Is using threads the best way to do this or not? What other possible ways are there?

upendra

Answer (score 0):

Get your Windows Service app to store the data to disk (xml or SDF for example).  Your Web application could then access the same data store...

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to use an .Net Queue to read the values from. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.71).aspx

Your other options would be to write the data to a file or a DB but then you have to write your own logic to handle disposing of read data which the Queue functionality will take care for you.

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

In similar scenario I used self-hosted WCF service within windows service. In this way you expose api to control the service and get information from it.

You can read more about WCF self-hosting in Michele Leroux's article : [link](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0701041)